# Dotnet publish vs publishing in Visual Studio generates a different $(PublishDir) in the csproj file

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue where the `$(PublishDir)` value is different depending on if I publish using the command line `dotnet publish -c release` or if I publish within Visual Studio.

Using the command line the PublishDir will be a relative path, using Visual Studio the publishDir will be an absolute path.

Here's the Pre-publish target which shows my problem. Basically I'm trying to compile my Angular application and place the outputs in the `$(PublishDir)/wwwroot` folder.

[image]

Is there any way to force the `$(PublishDir)` value to always be an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Directory.build.props file to specify a relative path for PublishDir always.  Generally speaking one should, IMHO, always use relative paths from the solution or project directory in builds.  The Directory.build.props file is processed before most of the common build files and generally allows you to override just about any property...

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and I just had to specify the PublishProfile for dotnet CLI to manage correctly the relative paths.

If you don´t have a publish profile go to your project on the project tree and click the "Publish.." button. It will promt with a Wizard in order to create a publish profile, you just can create a "Folder" publish profile for testing it.

After adding this publish profile a file with extension *.pubxml will be added at "YourProject\Properties\PublishProfiles"

At this point you just have to specify the publish profile at the dotnet command properties like this:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -p:"PublishProfile=FolderProfile"
```

I was using $(PublishDir) as well for and AfterPublish Target and this worked with dotnet CLI.